# having an array as class attribute

Tags: c++, arrays

sorry i'm new to c++ and i feel a little stupid for asking, but i can't get it to work after hours of googling and i can't find what i'm doing wrong

the task is pretty easy:

i want to have employees that have name, age etc (those work)
and i want these employees to be stored inside an array.

so i have:

```
class Employee {

public:
    Employee(string, string, int, int);
    string name;
    string firstName;
    int birthYear;
    int usedVacation;
    int getAge();
};
```

and then the list:

```
class EmployeeList {
public:
    int addEmployee(string, string, int, int);
    Employee eList[500];
};
```

what i want is: an object that holds an array of `Employee`s, with methods to add/edit etc them.
so i define the `addEmployee` method outside the class as follows:

```
int EmployeeList::addEmployee(string first, string last, int year, int used) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < this.eList.length; i++) {
        if (this.eList[i].deleted == true) {
            this.eList[i] = {
            firstName: first,
            lastName : last,
            birthYear : year,
            usedVacation : used,
            deleted : false };
    } else {
            this.eList.push({ firstName: first, lastName : last, birthYear : year, usedVacation : used, deleted : false });
    }
    return i;
    }
};
```

As you probably instantly see, there's a lot wrong with that.

All of the `this` throw `Expression must have class type` in VS2015,
also `identifier firstName is undefined` and `identifier lastName is undefined`,
but in my eyes, there's nothing wrong with my code.

i'm pretty sure this is a very basic thing i just didn't get yet, but i just can't find out, where the problem is.

I defined methods outside `Employee`, and `this` works there without a problem (although with `this->`, but i tried that and it doesn't work either)

please forgive my lack of skills, i come from javascript :(

Comment: It's `this->member` not `this.member` and it isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: You're probably better off with a `std::vector<Employee> eList;`

Comment: Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it's for class, i can't use vectors :(

Comment: @user3787706: There's a lot wrong with this code - it's not an answerable question other than: get a better book or take a better class.  Your professor apparently taught you nothing about arrays nor classes.

Comment: Why do courses insist on students _not_ using vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this.eList[i] =

`this` is a pointer, not a reference, so you access the members via `this->eList`.  But 99.99% of the time, it's completely unnecessary.  You're inside a member method, so the compiler knows what `this` is.  All you need is `eList[i] =`.

> this.eList.push({

First a brief tutorial with arrays in C++.  `Employee eList[500]` doesn't make an array that can hold 500 `Employee`s, `eList` *is* 500 `Employee`s.   Forever and always. They are are instantly constructed with the default constructor (or will be once you give `Employee` a default constructor.  This is required if you want to have objects in an array, except in very advanced cases).

> this.eList.length

There are three actions you can do with arrays: you can access an element with the [i] syntax, they magically convert to a pointer to the first item very often, and finally, if and only if they're a member of a struct, they can be copied.  That's all you can do with them.  There is no push, because as I said, it *is* 500 `Employee`.  There is no `length` member.  Yours is always 500 `Employee`s.

> if (this.eList[i].deleted == true)

You gave each `Employee` 4 members, `deleted` was not one of them.  Instead of keeping track of which `Employee` objects are unused, the normal thing is to keep all the employees in the first few slots, and give `EmployeeList` a `count` to keep track of how many "live" employees there are.  The live ones are in indecies 0-count.  The employees at count-500 are "deleted".  Unfortunately, this does mean that when one is deleted, you have to shift forward all the ones after that.

> this.eList[i] = {
>               firstName: first,
>               lastName : last,

`Employee` does not have a `lastName`.  The right way to construct an `Employee` is via the constructor you declared: `Employee(string, string, int, int)`. So that line should probably be `eList[i] = Employee(first, last, year, used);`.  This creates a new `Employee` object, and then copies it into that slot of the array. Alternatively, just assign the members one by one.

Comment: thanks. that's a good starting point. i noticed some things i could have known better. i'm gonna look into the whole array mechanics, that's pretty confusing to me right now

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
#include<string>

class Employee
{
  public:
    std::string firstname;
    std::lastname;
    int birthyear;
    int usedVacation;

    void setFirstname(std::string fname){firstname = fname;}
    void setLastname(std::string lname){lastname = lname;}
    void setBirthyear(int year){birthyear = year;}
    void setVacation(int vac){usedVacation = vac;}
};


class EmployeeList
{
  public:
    int count;
    EmployeeList eList[500];

    EmployeeList()
    {
      count = 0;
    }

    void addEmployee(std::string fname, std::string lname, int year, int vac);
    void removeEmployee(std::string fname, std::string lname, int year, int vac);
};


void EmployeeList::addEmployee(std::string fname, std::string lname, int year, int vac)
{
  //some stuff goes here
  count++;
}

void EmployeeList::removeEmployee(std::string fname, std::string lname, int year, int vac)
{
  //some stuff goes here
  count--;
}
```

BTW I am not sure where your push, deleted, and length methods came from? You will likely also want to add more methods then what I have written, for example a method to return count. You can also add get methods to the employee class and make your member variables private. I hope this is of some help. Goodluck!